# How to give a mocked value to a function which needs a reference with the 'static lifetime and implements Sync?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rust, type-conversion

I used [mocker](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers/blob/0.9.4/README.md) to test my project. I have no idea what kind of type conversion is needed by `say_hello_brother`. The simplified code list below:

**lib.rs**

```
#![feature(plugin, custom_derive)]
#![plugin(mockers_macros)]
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate mockers;

use mockers::Scenario;

#[derive(Mock)]
trait SayHello {
    fn hello(&self);
}

// assume `SayHello` is a service and  worked on multiple threads
fn say_hello_brother<T: SayHello + Sync>(brother: &'static T) {
    brother.hello()
}

#[test]
fn test_sya_hello() {
    let scenario = Scenario::new();
    let mock = scenario.create_mock_for::<SayHello>();
    say_hello_brother(&mock)
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "mock"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["llxxb"]

[dependencies]
mockers = "0.9.4"
mockers_macros = "0.9.4"
```

and error info:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<mockers::ScenarioInternals>>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `SayHelloMock`
  --> src\lib.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     say_hello_brother(&mock)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<mockers::ScenarioInternals>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `SayHelloMock`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<mockers::ScenarioInternals>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `SayHelloMock`
```

**UPDATE** After some trying, I succeed to attach `Sync` to `SayHelloMock`. the new lib.rs:

```
#![feature(plugin, custom_derive)]
#![plugin(mockers_macros)]
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate mockers;

use mockers::Scenario;

trait SayHello {
    fn hello(&self);
}


mock! {
    SayHelloMock,
    self,
    trait SayHello {
        fn hello(&self);
    }
}

unsafe impl Sync for SayHelloMock {}


// assume `SayHello` is a service and  worked on multiple threads
fn say_hello_brother<T: SayHello + Sync>(brother: &'static T) {
    brother.hello()
}

#[test]
fn test_sya_hello() {
    let scenario = Scenario::new();
// not work
//    let mock = scenario.create_mock::<SayHelloMock>();
//    static MOCK: SayHelloMock = || { mock };
//    say_hello_brother(&MOCK)

    // not work yet
    let mock : &'static SayHelloMock = &(scenario.create_mock::<SayHelloMock>());
    say_hello_brother(mock)
}
```

But I still can't convert it to 'static, error info:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
--> src\lib.rs:38:41
|
38 |     let mock : &'static SayHelloMock = &(scenario.create_mock::<SayHelloMock>());
|                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
39 |     say_hello_brother(mock)
40 | }
| - temporary value only lives until here
|
= note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* use the mocker library for this purpose because the mocks it generates are [not thread safe](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers/issues/22).

That being said, nothing restricts you from creating your own mocks which are thread-safe:

```
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct MyMock {
    call_count: AtomicUsize,
}

impl SayHello for MyMock {
    fn hello(&self) {
        self.call_count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

However, your signature requires a `&'static T`, which is really probably a terrible idea. You will need to use something like a lazy-static:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

#[test]
fn test_say_hello() {
    lazy_static! { 
        static ref MOCK: MyMock = MyMock::default();
    };
    say_hello_brother(&*MOCK);
    assert_eq!(MOCK.call_count.load(Ordering::SeqCst), 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I think this way is too simple for test. In real test not only need called count, but also parameter check, more importantly the parameter may be different for every call. But the `lazy_static` is new for me, I'll try and take it

Comment: @llxxbb based on the code you have provided, there is literally *nothing else* that can be tested beyond the total number of calls. Of course, the solution here can be extended and complicated for a near infinite amount of permutations.

Comment: yeah. you said right, but  I do not like by making a lots of mock structs instead of a good mock framework yet. The mock framework can simplify the code structure and easy to understand.

Comment: @llxxbb `#[derive(Mock)]` *creates those structs*. You aren't avoiding them, just the work of typing them out. Anyway, this answer gives you the capabilities to submit a PR to that library to make the mocks it generates `Send` and `Sync`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little vague, but if I understood correctly, you want to know how you could pass that mock to function `say_hello_brother`. The problem is that that function expects an object that implements the `Sync` trait as well. For this reason, you cannot convert `mock` to some other type to get the code to compile.

According to the [documentation of *mocker*](https://github.com/kriomant/mockers/blob/0.9.4/doc/guide.md#inherited-traits--mocking-several-traits), you could try mocking two traits at once. Here is some pseudo-code that illustrates the idea:

```
mock! {
    SayHelloMock,
    self,
    trait SayHello {
        // trait methods here
    },
    self,
    trait Sync {
        // trait methods here
    }
}
```

Then in your test, you would create a mock like this:

```
let mut mock = scenario.create_mock::<SayHelloMock>();
```

Comment: [@Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835286/marko-popovic) Are you sure it can work？ I got another error :error[E0200]: the trait `std::marker::Sync` requires an `unsafe impl` declaration

Comment: @llxxbb I know you can mock two traits at once so I suggested to try this approach, I did not try it out with this concrete example. Did you try marking Sync as unsafe: `unsafe trait Sync`?

Comment: I tried ,and then error again : Unsafe traits are not supported yet, but I make it work by add "unsafe impl Sync for SayHelloMock {}". But I can't add `'static` lifetime to the mock,  please see question I appended.