# How to inject a stub for a trait object into a type in Rust and keep a reference to it?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, stub, borrow-checker

I'm trying to develop some kind of time tracking CLI tool in Rust. I try to cover most of the code with unit tests and got stuck about how to use stub objects with Rusts ownership restrictions.

I have a type `Tracker` which has functions to start/stop tracking time. These functions query the current system time.

To make this design testable I introduced the trait `TimeService` which provides the current timestamp. I have the "real" implementation `SystemTimeService` which returns the current system time and a fake implementation `FakeTimeService` for tests where the time can be set from the outside.

This is the current implementation:

```rust
pub struct Tracker {
    // ...
    time_service: Box<TimeService>,
}

trait TimeService {
    fn time(&self) -> u64;
}
```

Here is the test I'd like to implement:

```rust
#[test]
fn tracker_end_when_called_tracks_total_time() {
    let (tracker, time_service) = init_tracker();

    time_service.set_seconds(0);
    tracker.start("feature1");
    time_service.set_seconds(10);
    tracker.end();

    assert_eq!(tracker.total_time, 10);
}

fn init_tracker() -> (Tracker, &FakeTimeService) {
    let time_service = Box::new(FakeTimeService::new());
    let tracker = Tracker::with_time_service(time_service);

    // does not compile, as time service's ownership has been
    // moved to the tracker.
    (tracker, &*time_service)
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the fake time service from inside the unit test as it's ownership is taken by the tracker.

I can imagine multiple solutions:

1. Use `Rc` instead of `Box` inside the tracker for shared ownership of the time service
2. Make the `Tracker` generic and add a type argument for the used `TimeTracker` implementation
3. Add lifetimes to the `init_tracker` function

I do not like using solution 1 as this would not express the idea that the service is part of the tracker (seems to violate encapsulation).

Solution 2 is probably viable but in that case I'd need to make the `TimeService` trait and the used implementations public which I'd also like to avoid.

So the most promising solution without changing the design seems to be lifetimes.
Is it possible to add lifetimes to the variables in such a way that the `init_tracker` function can return the tracker and the fake time service?

Are there any other solutions/best practices?

Comment: See also [How to give a mocked value to a function which needs a reference with the 'static lifetime and implements Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49093092/155423); [How can I test stdin and stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28370126/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you, especially the second links is very interesting. This would've been my solution 2. I just did not want to make the `TimeService` trait public in this case.

Comment: [You don't have to make it public for unit tests](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b07367b6ed35d6843526b3a4f716b26).

Comment: I was thinking about the stdin/stdout testing example. In that case I'd have a `Tracker<T: TimeService>` and would need to make the `TimeService` trait public. Your example is very instructive, though, thank you.

Comment: Right, but your code uses a trait object, so you don't need the generic. See also [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `FakeTimeService` type cloneable, making its state shared across multiple cloned instances:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct FakeTimeService {
    state: Rc<FakeTimeServiceState>,
}

impl TimeService for FakeTimeService { ... }

impl FakeTimeService {
    fn state(&self) -> &FakeTimeServiceState {
        *self.state
    }
}

fn init_tracker() -> (Tracker, FakeTimeService) {
    let time_service = FakeTimeService::new();
    let tracker = Tracker::with_time_service(Box::new(time_service.clone()));
    (tracker, time_service)
}
```

Now you'll be able to independently modify the fake time service state, while keeping the interface and implementation of the `Tracker` the same as before.

Most likely you'll want to have some mutable state inside `FakeTimeService` in order to set up your test preconditions. Therefore, you will probably need to use some kind of internal mutability for the `FakeTimeService` state:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

#[derive(Clone)]
struct FakeTimeService {
    state: Rc<RefCell<FakeTimeServiceState>>,
}

impl FakeTimeService {
    fn state_mut(&self) -> RefMut<FakeTimeServiceState> {
        self.state.borrow_mut()
    }
}

struct FakeTimeServiceState {
    init_value: i32,
}

impl FakeTimeServiceState {
    fn set_initial_value(&mut self, x: i32) {
        self.init_value = x;
    }
}

let (tracker, time_service) = init_tracker();
time_service.state_mut().set_initial_value(123);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my question perfectly and I really like this solution.